# Using JMAP on Sun WebServer 6.1 Instance

Tags: webserver, sunone, jmap

I have a webapp running on Sun One WebServer and I would like to use jmap to dump the heap space memory. When I list the processes running on my server, no java processes are listed, but only webservd processes (controlled by Sun WebServer).

How do I use jmap with Sun WebServer 6.1 servers? I don't have access to the jvm's pid....

The syntax which I would like to use is:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin PID
```

where PID is the missing piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Using jps -l -m I can get the list of active pid numbers and then I can compare them with the webservd PIDs to figure out which one to dump.